# Why can't I get Crushing Blow 2?

Tags: the-witcher

So it's my understanding that in order to get a "second tier" skill, you need the first one.  I have the entire tree filled out in level 1 for Strong Steel, and I have 2 bronze talents available for myself to use - but for some reason, I can't actually click on the Crushing Blow II skill in my skill tree?  I have screenshots of what I mean here:

[Can't pick this one?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZtUT.jpg)

[Highlighted (I can pick this one!)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7i2x5.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid it looks like that you have already got it.

Also when using the FCR modification, then there's a bug when you still need to have a silver talent available in order to spend a bronze one (it doesn't touch this question):

> Sign power-ups cost a bronze talent, but you need to have at least one silver
>   (or gold later) talent. Silver talents are not spent in learning the power-up. This
>   bug is caused by the mod, but its source lies in the game. The modification
>   does not have errors itself, and for now there is no solution for this problem.